# How to test a void method using JUnit and/or Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

Apologies in advance - I know this has been asked a thousand times but I've looked through so many articles/documentation and I'm just so f****** lost.

I have a class that takes in an XML file and then uses DocumentBuilder to parse it into a new file that will be used as a source for other classes to use.

I need to test my method (which is void). My project is completed but I need to test.

If anyone could be so kind to show me how this would be done, I can go ahead and follow that same logic with my other classes, as 90% of the methods in my project do not return anything.

Thanks...

```
 public class XmlToCsv {


    public static void xmlToCsv(String sourceXlsFile, String sourceCsvFile, String sourceXmlFile) throws Exception {

        //define the files
        File stylesheet = new File(sourceXlsFile);
        File xmlSource = new File(sourceXmlFile);

        //create the DocumentBuilder to parse the XML file
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(xmlSource);

        //input the stylesheet to transform the XML to
        StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(stylesource);

        //write a new output file using the stylesheet format
        Source source = new DOMSource(document);
        Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(new File(sourceCsvFile));
        transformer.transform(source, outputTarget);

    }
}
```

Comment: The fact that the method under test returns nothing is irrelevant. The test is performed by seeing what **observable effects** the call does and asserting on those. Wheter those effects are done via a return value or by modifying other things change a bit the test, but the logic is pretty much the same.

Comment: That's strange. Could have sworn testing void/non-void methods are two different entities.

Comment: Not really, code will be a little different, but the overall process is the same. Instead of asserting against a return value, you assert against some **side effects** instead (or in addition to). Those could be the state of the parameter objects, some global state, a file system or DB change, or whatever else, depending on what the method does. A return value is just one of the things a method could do, but not the only.

Comment: I see. So then my test method for this class is **asserting** that a file is being created. That's my side effect. Still not sure how to format that into the dbfactory and stream/transformer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you trying to do is actually not the way to do it. You should test ONLY the `XmlToCsv` class and not the classes that are used by this class (`DocumentBuilderFactory`, `DocumentBuilder`, `Document`, `StreamSource`, `Transformer`, `Source`, `Result`).

There are now 2 ways you can go: The clean code way, or the dirty test way.

The best solution is that you have a dependency framework for the classes you use:

```
public class XmlToCsv {

    @Inject
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory;

    @Inject
    StreamSource stylesource;

    @Inject
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory;

    public void xmlToCsv(String sourceXlsFile, String sourceCsvFile, String sourceXmlFile) throws Exception {

        //define the files
        File stylesheet = new File(sourceXlsFile);
        File xmlSource = new File(sourceXmlFile);

        //create the DocumentBuilder to parse the XML file
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(xmlSource);

        //input the stylesheet to transform the XML to
        StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(stylesource);

        //write a new output file using the stylesheet format
        Source source = new DOMSource(document);
        Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(new File(sourceCsvFile));
        transformer.transform(source, outputTarget);

    }
}
```

Testing now can be done by injecting mocks into the injectable fields:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class XmlToCsvTest {
    @Mock
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory;

    @Mock
    StreamSource style source;

    @Mock
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory;

    @InjectMocks
    XmlToCsv sut; // System Under Test

    @Test
    public void testOk() throws Exception {
        // Mocks
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = Mockito.mock(DocumentBuilder.class);
        Document document = Mockito.mock(Document.class);
        // Now you control all objects created in the class and you can test if the right methods are called

        // when-clauses
        Mockito.when(factory.newDocumentBuilder).thenReturn(documentBuilder);
        Mockito.when(documentBuilder.parse(any(File.class)).thenReturn(document);
        // Add all when's here

        // now call the class
        sut.xmlToCsv("", "", "");

        // now verify all calls
        verify(factory, times(1)).newDocumentBuilder();
        verify(documentBuilder, times(1)).parse(any(File.class));
        // etc.
    }
}
```

The dirty way is using PowerMockito. With PowerMockito you can override the new methods of existing classes. It is really a last resort and I wouldn't recommend it, but you can use it when you can't change the source code. It will look something like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({XmlToCsv.class, DocumentBuilderFactory.class})
public class XmlToCsvTest {

    XmlToCsv sut;

    @Test
    public void testXmlToCsv() throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = Mockito.mock(DocumentBuilder.class);
        Document document = Mockito.mock(Document.class);

        //when phase
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance).thenReturn(documentBuilder);
        Mockito.when(factory.newDocumentBuilder).thenReturn(documentBuilder);
        Mockito.when(documentBuilder.parse(any(File.class)).thenReturn(document);

        // now call the class
        sut.xmlToCsv("", "", "");

        //now verify

verify(documentBuilder, times(1)).parse(any(File.class));
    }
}
```

As you see the examples aren't complete, but you get the difference.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the way you'd want to test this method is to validate the expected contents of the file written to the `sourceCsvFile` argument, which you could do by reading in the contents after your method is called. I don't think you need to do anything with Mockito - all of your arguments are String objects, and so there's no need to create any mocks.

Comment: They're strings, but they're strings which should represent paths to files.

Comment: Yes, the parameters I'm passing through represent the paths to the files (sourceXlsFile, sourceCsvFile, sourceXmlFile) are some of the source files I use in my project.

Comment: Since they're the paths to the files, and those files are being created/modified, then it would seem like the appropriate test would be to open those files after this method is called in test and see that the contents are correct.

Answer (score 1):

To test a code generator, this is the best approach I found:

1. Prepare a set of **test cases** with the same XSL: For each one, an XML input file and an expected CSV output file. Put the input files into a directory, and the expected ones into another one, but set the same names for each pair of files (`case1.xml` and `case1.csv`).
2. Code a JUnit class with a private method which should do the test and the comparison, and then add one `@Test` method for each case you want to test:

   ```
   import java.io.File;
   import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

   public class XmlToCsvTest
   {
     private final File inputDir=new File("my_input_xml_files");

     private final File expectedDir=new File("my_expected_csv_files");

     private final File generatedDir=new File("my_generated_files"); // This is just a working dir

     private void xmlToCsv(String xslFile, String inputFileName)
     {
       try
       {
         File inputXmlFile=new File(this.inputDir, inputFileName + ".xml");
         File outputCsvFile=new File(this.generatedDir, inputFileName + ".csv");
         File expectedCsvFile=new File(this.expectedDir, inputFileName + ".csv");
         xmlToCsv(xslFile, outputCsvFile.getAbsolutePath(), inputXmlFile.getAbsolutePath());
         FileUtils.contentEquals(expectedCsvFile, outputCsvFile);
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
         fail(e.toString());
       }
     }

     @Test
     public void xmlToCsvWithCase1()
     {
       xmlToCsv("myFirst.xsl", "case1");
     }

     @Test
     public void xmlToCsvWithEmptyFile()
     {
       xmlToCsv("myFirst.xsl", "empty");
     }

     @Test
     public void xmlToCsvWithOneRow()
     {
       xmlToCsv("myFirst.xsl", "one-row");
     }

       ...
   }
   ```
3. Once you have mastered this technique, you can add more complexity to your tests, by adding other XSLs, with its own testing cases.

Don't forget to add the set of files to your project as resources, to become part of the source control system.

Note: This approach assumes that each output file depends only on the contents of the input file. If the generator adds some independent content (as the current date, current user, or so) a previous pre-processing must be done.